# Can we use "paypal payment method" for indian shopping website

Tags: magento, paypal, payment

we are planning to use "paypal payment method" as payment option for

indian shopping site.

Assume Indian customers[buyers of products] have paypal account & Owner/admin of the site have paypal

account.

IS it possible to use"paypal" in indian shopping sites.

IF so, is it possible to pay use "online net banking through paypal" for all banks.

please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to let you know PayPal have introduced auto withdrawal policy for Indian Accounts in order to follow the guidelines of Indian Government which ultimately leads that Indian PayPal account can't store their PayPal money within their account and it will be deducted automatically at certain interval. This leads to no shopping or mere shopping scenario for Indian customers through their PayPal Accounts.

Reference link :- [PayPal Withdrawal policy for India](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/About-Settings-Archive/How-to-Turn-Off-Auto-Withdrawal/td-p/644256)

Comment: hi,

Thanks a lot for reply. 

I assume you are telling we can not use paypal in indian shopping website.
am i right?

Comment: Yes exactly. Through PayPal Indian users ultimately won't be able to store there amount within it so not possible after current Government laws.